# Storing a line drawn onto an image by user C#

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, graphics

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that allows the user to draw onto an image. I would like to be able to store the path that the user drew onto the image.

So say, for instance, the user draws a line that goes all the way across the image. I want to store the entire path so that when the user leaves the app and comes back, they can click a button and the app will redraw the path from earlier onto the image.

My question is: How do you store the entire coordinates of the line that is drawn by the user?

Here is my current code:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }
    private WriteableBitmap writeableBmp;
    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Init WriteableBitmap
        writeableBmp = new WriteableBitmap(OrginalImage, null);
        writeableBmp.Invalidate();
    }
    private void AlterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ImagePixelsAlter(new ExecuteAction((bitmap) => { AlterImage.Source = bitmap; }));
    }  
    public void ImagePixelsAlter(ExecuteAction action)
    {
        WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(OrginalImage, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < writeableBitmap.Pixels.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                writeableBitmap.Pixels.SetValue(-95756, i);
            }
        }

        action(writeableBitmap);
    }
    public delegate void ExecuteAction(WriteableBitmap bitmap);    
    private void Image_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var mp = GetMousePoint(e);
        writeableBmp.FillRectangle(mp.X, mp.Y, mp.X +5, mp.Y +5, Colors.Red);
        OrginalImage.Source = writeableBmp;
    }
    private ControlPoint GetMousePoint(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        return new ControlPoint(e.GetPosition(OrginalImage));
    }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: My question is: How do you store the entire coordinates of the line that is drawn by the user?